# Filter geojson points in Leaflet without clustering them

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've found a [great example](http://www.digital-geography.com/filter-leaflet-maps-slider/) of how to filter leaflet points with a slider.

I would like to use this, but without the MarkerCluster clustering.

But I'm getting a "too much recursion" error in JS. May I please ask what's wrong with my code:

```
var popplaces = new L.geoJson(exp_popplaces,{
    onEachFeature: pop_popplaces,
    pointToLayer: popplaces_marker
});
```

[..]

```
slidervar.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    console.log(handle);
    if (handle==0){
        document.getElementById('input-number-min').value = values[0];
    } else {
        document.getElementById('input-number-max').value =  values[1];
    }
    rangeMin = document.getElementById('input-number-min').value;
    rangeMax = document.getElementById('input-number-max').value;
    ////first let's clear the layer:
    //cluster_popplaces.clearLayers();
    popplaces.clearLayers();
    ////and repopulate it
    popplaces = new L.geoJson(exp_popplaces,{
        onEachFeature: pop_popplaces,
        filter:
            function(feature, layer) {
                 return (feature.properties.pop_max <= rangeMax) && (feature.properties.pop_max >= rangeMin);
            },
        pointToLayer: popplaces_marker
    })
    //and back again into the cluster group
    //cluster_popplaces.addLayer(popplaces);
    popplaces.addLayer(popplaces);
});
```

Here is my full source: index_raw_cluster.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a var to itself:

```
popplaces.addLayer(popplaces);
```

this is indeed too much recursion.